# Combining 2 different value into 1 in SQL

Tags: sql

First of all, I apologize for not being able to show my question with code. I have 2 tables. I'm merging these tables and returning a result. My values ​​include values ​​that are the same but written with different letters ( for example, INSTALL and INSTALL). These two values ​​are essentially the same. but it returns 2 different results because they are written with different letters. what I want is to convert the İNSTALL value to the INSTALL value and increase the total INSTALL value to 5. Any idea?

| Column1 | Values |
| --- | --- |
| INSTALL | 2 |
| İNSTALL | 3 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please show some more sample data.

Comment: why not use a trim and upper to force the groupings by column1

Comment: What is the collation of the column?

Comment: @GoldenLion I tried but I couldn't.

Comment: use a case when to group the similar words together and then group on that case statement

Comment: What happens if you try casting to `varchar` and then grouping?

Comment: @Stu i'll try it

Comment: A Turkish I? Uppercase I with dot above

Answer (score 0):

Use UPPER() function available in different DBMS.

```
select UPPER(Column1),sum(values) from Table group by UPPER(Column1)
```

UPPER: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_upper.asp

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the anticipated overlap of letters, you could go about this a couple of ways.

Assuming the headers are the same across both tables, and only the cases are different (if they're not, use aliases in the CTE):

```
SELECT 
LOWER(column_1) AS column_1,
SUM(Values) AS values_total
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1 UNION SELECT * FROM table_2) combined_tables
GROUP BY 1
```

If there is different spelling across both tables, you could use a lower case cast of only the rightmost or leftmost letters.

```
SELECT 
LOWER(RIGHT(column_1),3) AS column_1,
SUM(Values) AS values_total
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1 UNION SELECT * FROM table_2) combined_tables
GROUP BY 1
```

If you expect a mix of misspellings, non-text characters, I'd suggest using regex to do fuzzy matching on the column values.